# AngularJS $translate.refresh() not working on load

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm testing Angular-translate with angular-traslate-partial-loader and it is not populating the page with the default translation on page load.

here is a plunkr of the problem recreated

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$translate', '$translatePartialLoader',
  function($scope, $translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('test');
    $translate.refresh();
    $scope.dotranslate = function() {
      $translate.refresh();
    };
  }
]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Vts9CW4VoJsXoSdllFsq?p=preview

I added a refresh button to show that the $translate.refresh() works after page load.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 3):

I've never used $translate so I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, but you may be changing a value too late in the digest cycle for the refresh to catch it.

You can use $scope.$evalAsync to fix this. See the angular documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Here is an example of your app.js with the change:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['pascalprecht.translate']);
app.config(function run($translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {
  $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
    urlTemplate: 'translation-{lang}-{part}.json'
  });

  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('fr-FR');
});
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$translate', '$translatePartialLoader',
  function($scope, $translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('test');

    //I wrapped your refresh in the eval async function
    $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
      $translate.refresh();
    });

    $scope.dotranslate = function() {
      $translate.refresh();
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thank James that was exactly the issue. And a great example of when and why to use $scope.$evalAsync(). That's exactly what I was looking for. It's weird that it's not built in to the $translate.refresh() method.

Comment: It's probably not built into the translate refresh because it isn't always needed. Like I said, I haven't looked at the $translate module at all, but my guess is that had $translatePartialLoader.addPart('test') been called earlier in the life cycle (maybe during the module run phase) then the $evalAsync might not have been necessary. Anyways, glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the answer when you can.

Comment: well it worked on my plunker, but not in my application. It's certainly a timing thing, as you're saying. The refresh is being called before the partial is being loaded.

Comment: Try running the partial loader in your module run function. Use app.run(['$translatePartialLoader', function($translatePartialLoader) { $translatePartialLoader.addPart('test'); }]);

Comment: Try this, in place of $scope.$evalAsync use setTimeout(function() { $translate.refresh(); }, 0); Setting a timeout to zero will allow the DOM to render before calling your refresh function. You may need to call an $apply as well within the timeout function.

Comment: thanks for sticking with me James... that definitely worked. I've also got some messages into the angular-traslate team as this is either a bug in their code or I'm doing something wrong. It certainly can't be the intended result. thanks again.

Comment: Yes, I think this is something they should probably resolve. Glad I could help.